# Coroutine async not happening in order

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am wring data to Firestore and I wish to get confirmation about it, but this not work in correct order, although the write is successful I still get *false* in successful.

In Fragment:

```
buttonUpload.setOnClickListener {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val done = FirestoreHelper.addUnit(unitId, dataMap)
            Log.d(TAG, "Done: " + done)
        }
    }
```

FirestoreHelper:

```
object FirestoreHelper {

private var firestore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

init {
    firestore.firestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().build()
}

suspend fun addUnit(unitId: String, dataMap: HashMap<String, Any>): Boolean = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

    val docID = firestore.collection(INSTALLERS).document(unitId)
    val task = firestore.collection(INSTALLERS).document(docID.id).set(dataMap)

    task.isSuccessful

}
```

}

Comment: How does this `but this not work in correct order` and `although the write is successful I still get false in successful` relate, maybe I have hard time understanding the question.

Comment: The "task.isSuccessful" is false. So this probably the default value so it returns before the task is happened. In bottom line, it should be true.

Comment: @Dim Why do you expect `task.isSuccessful` to be true immediately? `Task` is asynchronous, you should add [listener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnSuccessListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener%3C?%20super%20TResult%3E)) or use [`await`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/await.html) extension.

Comment: `set()` returns [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html). I don't know anything about it, but I suppose it's asynchronous, and it's not finished yet at the time of `task.isSuccessful` call. I think you need to use onCompleteListener or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `set()` is an asynchronous function that returns [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html) (and executes the network request in different thread).

You can await for the result using [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html):

```kotlin
suspend fun addUnit(unitId: String, dataMap: HashMap<String, Any>): Boolean =
        suspendCoroutine { cont ->
            val docID = firestore.collection(INSTALLERS).document(unitId)
            firestore.collection(INSTALLERS)
                    .document(docID.id)
                    .set(dataMap)
                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                        if (it.isSuccessful) cont.resume(it.isSuccessful)
                        else cont.resumeWithException(it.getException())
                    }
        }
```

Or there is already an adapter in the `play-services-ktx` extension library, you can add dependency to that and directly call `Task.await()` to get result of the task or exception will be thrown there.

Answer (score 1):

The [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) is inherently an asynchronous operation. In order to get when the task is completed, you need to add a completion listener.

In order to do that with coroutines *synchronously*, you can either create your own [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) or use [Kotlin's Coroutines Integration with Play Services' Tasks API](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services).

To start using the integration please follow the steps below:

1. Add to your build.gradle

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines:play-services:${coroutinesVersion}"
```

2. Then you need to convert your code to

```kotlin
suspend fun addUnit(unitId: String, dataMap: HashMap<String, Any>): Boolean = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val docID = firestore.collection(INSTALLERS).document(unitId)
    val task = firestore.collection(INSTALLERS).document(docID.id).set(dataMap).await()

    task.isSuccessful
}
```